# INSERT into a table records extracted from another table, ACCESS wrong result, duplicates

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, sql-insert

I create a query of duplicates (which I name R1) from 2 tables with the following sql and it gives me the right result, eg. only one value is in duplicity among the 2 tables P1 and P2

```
SELECT CAB
FROM (SELECT P1.CAB AS CAB FROM P1
UNION ALL SELECT P2.CAB FROM P2)  AS Tmp
GROUP BY Tmp.CAB
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

However when i try to insert this value in another table of duplicates with the following code :

```
INSERT INTO aux_DBL (CAB) SELECT CAB
FROM (R1)
```

Access inserts 2 values instead of the one value of R1. The first CAB inserted into aux_DBL is the first CAB of the table P1 if I sort P1 ascending by CAB, which is not in duplicity not in P1, not in P2, not in the combination

I have no clue whatsoever!!

EDIT: I am using Access 2007, my file is mdb,  and P1 and P2 are linked tables one to sqlite the other to another mdb

EDIT2: The sample database is here http://www.filedropper.com/mysample

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue in Access 2010. When I run your INSERT query only one row is inserted. Please [edit] your question to include a **small** sample dataset that *you have tested* to confirm that it will recreate the issue. Also mention the version of Access that you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon Thank you, I prepared my database with local tables (the same error) but having difficulty to upload it to the same site (the image with code not showing anything).  Can i send it to some email?

Comment: Still unable to recreate. Downloaded your sample database and when I run the [R2] insert query it only appends one row for 'BGMK14'.

Comment: Well, Thank you Gordon, I do again and it appends 2 records (49WFS5 and BGMK14). Your result is what I expected but mine is clearly a mistake. I appreciate you taking the time to download and everything

Comment: No problem. My previous test was with Access 2010. I just tried again with Access 2007 and got the same result: only one row appended. Sorry.